# console.log prints changed state before changing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to rearrange div's with React/Redux via Drag&Drop and there is a strange behavoir that i cant explain. I have the following reducer (reduced version for readability)

There are 5 "console.log" around the middle of the code. When i log **state** or **structs** the chrome console will print the already rearrange version. why?

```
export default function reducer(
    state={
        structures: [],
        elementUniqueCounter: 0,
        hoveredElement: null,
        DnD: {
            dragContent: null,
            dragOverContent: null,
            dragContentTop: true,
            dragStructure: null,
            dragOverStructure: null,
            dragStructureTop: true,
            content: null,
            mousepositon: {}
        }
    }, action) {
    let DnD = Object.assign({}, state.DnD);
    let structs = state.structures.slice();
    switch (action.type) {
        case "STOP_DRAG_CONTENT":
            let cindex_source;
            let index_source;
            let cindex_target;
            let index_target;
            let foundTarget = false;
            let foundSource = false;

            structs.map(function (struct, index) {
                struct.content.map(function (content, cindex) {
                    if(content.id === DnD.dragOverContent.props.id) {
                        cindex_target = cindex;
                        index_target = index;
                        foundTarget = true;
                    }
                    if(content.id === DnD.dragContent.props.id) {
                        cindex_source = cindex;
                        index_source = index;
                        foundSource = true;
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(state);
            console.log(index_source);
            console.log(cindex_source);
            console.log(index_target);
            console.log(cindex_target);
            if(index_source !== undefined && cindex_source !== undefined && index_target !== undefined && cindex_target !== undefined) {
                let copy = structs[index_source].content.slice(cindex_source, cindex_source+1)[0];
                copy.content = DnD.content;
                structs[index_source].content.splice(cindex_source, 1);
                if (DnD.dragContentTop) {
                    structs[index_target].content.splice(cindex_target+1, 0, copy);
                } else {
                    structs[index_target].content.splice(cindex_target, 0, copy);
                }
            }

            DnD = {
                dragContent: null,
                dragOverContent: null,
                dragContentTop: true,
                dragStructure: null,
                dragOverStructure: null,
                dragStructureTop: true,
                content: null,
                mousepositon: {}
            };
            return {...state, DnD: DnD, structures: structs};

    }

    return state
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it is printing the rearranged version before it happens. It is that it is printing an object that you are mutating. By the time you look at the object in the console the mutation has already occurred.

The use of `splice` is mutating.

```
structs[index_source].content.splice(cindex_source, 1);
if (DnD.dragContentTop) {
    structs[index_target].content.splice(cindex_target+1, 0, copy);
} else {
    structs[index_target].content.splice(cindex_target, 0, copy);
}
```

EDIT:

The above mutation is actually mutating the nested properties of `state.structures`. This is happening because [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a shallow copy of the original object.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

The objects in the shallow copy are just pointers to the objects in `state.structures`. So when you use `.splice()`, you mutate those referenced values.

Here is a snippet to illustrate this. Run it an look at the `console.log`.

```js
const people = [
 {
  name: "Joe",
  age: "52"
 },
 {
  name: "Sally",
  age: "48"
 }

];

const clonedPeople = people.slice();

console.log("people === clonedPeople: ", people === clonedPeople);
console.log("people[0] === clonedPeople[0]: ", people[0] === clonedPeople[0]);

const deeplyClonedPeople = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people));

console.log("people[0] === deeplyClonedPeople[0]: ", people[0] === deeplyClonedPeople[0]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i thought i can make a copy (not reference) with slice. That's why i used it before the switch (let structs = state.structures.slice();)

Comment: Yes but `slice` only returns a `shallow` copy and you're mutating nested properties. Instead of using `slice` try cloning your object with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.structures))`. Be aware that this method will remove `undefined` values from the resulting object.

Comment: I understand, didnt know that nested properties are an issue. Thanks